# Slint: With OpenGL / WebGL as backend, how do I combine 2 overlapping Images?

Tags: rust

If I have OpenGL / WebGL as Slint backend, how, if at all, can I combine 2 overlapping `Image` Widgets, so that the front `Image` inverts the back `Image`?

Like: Everything white on the front image stays white, except where it overlaps with something white of the back image, then it inverts that pixels to black.

I think it could be easily done in `GLSL` (maybe like `fragColor = background + foreground - 2.0 * background * foreground;`), which runs even on WebGL.

Reason:
I could do this by doing the math manually, but that could be quite expensive on a small Raspberry Pi (or other embedded Devices, one of Slints mainly targeted hardware groups). Using the 3D unit of the SoC should do it much faster, with much less power consumption.

Is there a way to access the shaders?

Comment: Oh, I see, you must do it like here: https://github.com/slint-ui/slint/blob/master/examples/opengl_texture/main.rs. More cumbersome than expected, but that seems to be the solution.